# How to get notifications: "an instance of the app crashed"

Tags: notifications, ibm-cloud

I'm using SDK for Node.js™ of Bluemix. I noticed in the activity log some notices about crashes:

```
an instance of the app crashed: 2 error(s) occurred:
* 2 error(s) occurred:
```

How can I receive these kind of notifications in my email?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite what you are asking for - it is higher level monitoring, but you could try using the [Availability Monitoring Service](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/availability-monitoring/) to monitor the overall status of your application:

> Be alerted on issues-via email, Slack, SMS or Push notification-BEFORE
>   they impact users. Create alert policies to reduce alert noise via
>   seamless integration with Alert Notification service

Another option may be to setup your own [syslog endpoint](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/monitor_log/logging/external/logging_external_hosts.html#thirdparty_logging), e.g. in a docker container and configure that to send alerts to you when your application crashes: https://serverfault.com/questions/32360/how-can-i-make-syslogd-email-certain-log-messages-to-me

Comment: I have the light version of this service running. But this is limited to availability. Just receiving the activity log that appears in the home page of the app seems more interesting.